# Permission to run arp commands on apache

Tags: python, linux, apache

I want to run 'arp or config' commands on apache using python

```
from mod_python import apache
```

I have tested codes but the output is empty or command not found.

I think that i need to give permission to apache to access this command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use absolute commands:

```
/sbin/arp
```